# Setting date picker's value to sysdate retrieves another date

Tags: oracle-apex

I am using Oracle APEX 21.1. I have an Interactive grid with a column of type SWITCH(FINISHED), and a column of type date picker(ACTUAL_DATE). I need to set the date picker to SYSDATE when FINISHED column's value changes. I created a dynamic action of type (SET VALUE - PL/SQL Expression) on the FINISHED column and set the Affected Column to ACTUAL_DATE. The value is changed but not to SYSDATE, it's changes to 25/02/08. And we are in 25/08/21. How is that possible?

Comment: sounds like a format issue. Are you passing the date format in all your statements ? Is it the same everywhere ? When you query the table (using TO_CHAR) - do you have the correct date ? What is the code you use to set the date ? Note that "SYSDATE" in a date picker will not give you the actual SYSDATE (date portion + time portion) but only the date portion - which is not really sysdate.

Comment: I tried setting it with only `SYSDATE` function as an expression. And tried it with `to_char(sysdate,'dd/mm/yy')`

Comment: Hard to help with this little info... I suggest you try to replicate the issue in a test app on the emp table (there is a hiredate column) and document exactly what you have done to get the issue.

Comment: `ws= eslam_ws
un=forhelp
pwd=Forhelp$
app=help
page=Home`

I renamed the table to **emps**.

Answer (score 1):

It works if you use another date format. I set the date format to DD-MON-YYYY and then it works fine. Check application 69168.

- Changed the date format for the hiredate column to DD-MON-YYYY
- Change the DA to return pl/sql expression `TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD-MON-YYYY')`

Comment: Do you think it is a bug?

Comment: change the date format settings under shared components > security attributes > globalization > application date format to DD/MM/YY, format mask of hiredate column to DD/MM/YY and expression to ```SYSDATE```. That works for me.